# Configure a Linksys WRT54G with dd-wrt for bridged client

Tags: router

I am looking to tether my phone's Wifi hotspot to a Linksys WRT54G flashed with dd-wrt. I need to provide wired access to several devices that have no Wifi.
Is this possible to do without a PC running after setting it up?

Comment: You need to set up a wireless bridge on your DD-WRT that connects to your phone's hotspot. After you have that set up, you shouldn't need a PC at all, unless you want to change some settings.

Comment: thanks for your response, how do I know what setting in the router to change? can you help me or point me where I  can get that info.

Comment: Did you check DD-WRT's wiki? If not here's a link for you http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge.

Comment: Shinjijai, thanks for the link for the repeater bridge, works great! I have been reading and trying this for a few days to no avail. This worked right from the star.